# Page refresh gives directory list for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, page-refresh

**I have created angular website and created many pages, when i run it's run properly, but when i refresh page F5 it fives me directory list. I have also attached file which showing error**.

[image]

When i refresh page, i want same page.

Comment: run the app using, `localhost:1491`, are you using any routes

Comment: yes, i'm using routing $urlRouterProvider and i given already route to page which i reload

Comment: dont take the url as, `localhost:1491/app/main`, just run it using `localhost:1491` and make a default route.

Comment: also, make sure your `index.html` is in the root of the application, outside the app folder

Comment: but i have many pages so i used route, and `app/main` is my second page my first page is login but it's working fine, but other pages give me directory list when i refresh.

Comment: yes my `index.html` page is outside of app folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139460/discussion-between-sravan-and-rvchauhan).